# extracting columns from tensor, tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice, convolution

Hi need to extract the columns from the `convo_2` variable in order to concatenate them into a single tensor (one column from each feature_map) but I don't know How to do that. I was trying to use `tf.while_loop()` and inside of it `tf.slice()` but I don't know if it can be the right choice. Can someone give an hint and maybe explain to me ho to use `tf.slice()`?

```
convo_1 = convolutional_layer(x, shape=[3, 3, 1, 64])
convo_1_pooling = max_pool_2by2(convo_1)

convo_2 = convolutional_layer(convo_1_pooling, shape=[3, 3, 64, 128])
```